# Node.js wrong UTF8 string representation, even though byte-codes seem correct

Tags: node.js, utf-8, base64

Having searched around for a while now, I believe my problem may not be directly related to what others had. I am using unicode chars in forms (using angularjs for client-side) and noticed that the UTF8 strings didn't display on the server logs properly. Thus I decided to base64.encode all strings on the client side before submitting to the server (nodejs/express4). The JSON data arrives properly to the server, but when I try to convert it from base64 to UTF8 using a buffer I'm getting different symbols. I tested the strings on http://www.base64decode.org/ and they decode fine. Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Example char: σ, base64="z4M=".
On the server this line decodes all JSON values to UTF8:

Object.keys(req.body).forEach(function(key) { req.body[key] = new Buffer(req.body[key], 'base64').toString('utf8'); });

And the "σ" char becomes "Ο" on the server. Anyone can assist?

Comment: How do you know it becomes "O" on the server? Do you print it? Where to?

Comment: I console.log() pretty much everything. It doesn't have to do with screen encoding though (it's set to UTF8 anyway), because I used .charCodeAt() to verify that the character codes are proper, which they are (03C3). However, node treats it as "O".

Answer (score 0):

> Thus I decided to base64.encode all strings on the client side before submitting to the server (nodejs/express4).

No need to, really. Probably the thing you were doing wrong with utf-8 json is also wrong now.
Try to debug that.

> noticed that the UTF8 strings didn't display on the server logs properly.

What do they display?
And on what OS are you?
Did you look at the logs with a hex viewer?

To me this looks like a typical "I have an a problem X, thought my solution half the way, but I am stuck with a sub-problem Y". Go back to X and attack it the right way (no base64).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
After recompiling nodejs from source the characters now appear normally. However, two binary equal strings produce different hmac keys on client and server side. I'm not sure if that's because of the hmac library. Still debugging...